# Populate html form select element with results from query on database table

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I am trying to make a form which includes a text input and a dropdown select element. The goal is to be able to enter text into the text box with a customer last name which will be used in a query. The results from the query then need to be placed in the select dropdown box for further use with the value being custID and the text being the first and last name of the customer and possibly there phone number. So far whenever I run it and enter any value I only get data[] and status: succesful in my alert box no matter what I input.

Here is the form and the ajax I have been playing with.

```
    <form  method="post" class="form-container" >
                <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Last name" 
                onkeyup="showCustomer(this.value)"><br>
                <select id = "custSelect" name="custSelect0" onchange="show(this)">
                <option value="">-- Select Customer--</option>
            </select><br>
    </form>
<script>

    function showCustomer(str) {
          //alert("click");
          var LastName = str;
          var ele = document.getElementById('custSelect');
       //alert (LastName);
       $.ajax({
            url:"getcustomer.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{customer:LastName},

            success:function(data, status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                //alert("Search succesful")
                    /*  $.each(data, function(i,item)) {
                          // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
                          ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
                              '<option value="' + data[i]['custId'] + '">' + data[i]['fname'] + ' ' + data[i]['lname'] + '</option>';
                      }*/
            }
          })
        }

        function show(ele) {
          // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
          var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
          msg.innerHTML = 'Selected Customer: <b>' + ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text + '</b> </br>' +
              'ID: <b>' + ele.value + '</b>';
}
    </script>
```

Here is the php file I am using to access the database and do the query. It is using PDO.

```
<?php

      require_once "configPDO.php";
    if(isset($_POST['customer'])){
      $customer = $_POST['customer'];
    
    
    $data = array();
    
    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM `customers`
    WHERE `LastName`
    LIKE '$customer'";
    
    $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
    //$statement->bind_param("s", $_GET['q']);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
    foreach($result as $row){
      $data[] = array(
        'custId' => $row["Cust_ID"],
        'fname' => $row["FirstName"],
        'lname' => $row["LastName"],
        'phone' => $row["PhoneNumber"],
        'altPhone' => $row["AltPhone"]
      );
    }
    
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: if you're getting `data[]` that suggests your query isn't returning anything. You need to add some wildcards for LIKE to do anything useful.Try `LIKE '%$customer%'"`

Comment: Unfortunately no change. getting the same thing. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Debug the PHP/MySQL part of this first of all then. Your code currently appears to have no error control implemented whatsoever (unless you set PDO to throw exceptions when you create the connection?), so you would not even notice if preparing the statement or executing the query failed.

Comment: Okay I know I need to work on security and I will before it's off my test server but for now how do I make it work

Comment: I have added error control to both the connection file and to my query file. I have also gone through setting up prepared statements and wildcards. I am now getting results back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking some of the suggested changes using info from this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcW8mMiIexc
and correcting the spelling of my table to search, I have been able to get it to return results back to the form.

```
<?php
      require_once "/home/users/web/b1240/dom.heather93124/public_html/resources/configPDO.php";
    if(isset($_POST['customer'])){
        $customer = $_POST['customer'];
    
        $data = array();
    
        try{
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Customer` WHERE `LastName` LIKE :customer";
          $customer = "%$customer%";
          $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindValue(':customer', $customer);
          $stmt->execute();
          while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $data[] = array(
              'custId' => $row["Cust_ID"],
              'fname' => $row["FirstName"],
              'lname' => $row["LastName"],
              'phone' => $row["PhoneNumber"],
              'altPhone' => $row["AltPhone"]
            );
            }
    
        echo json_encode($data);
        }catch(Exception $e){
          echo $e-getMessage();
        }
    }
    ?>
```